# pandas multiindex select one header value according to another header and a level

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, multi-index

I have this dataframe with multiple headers

```
name,   00590BL,    01090BL,    01100MS,    02200MS
lat,    613297, 626278, 626323, 616720
long,   5185127,    5188418,    5188431,    5181393
elv,    1833,   1915,   1915,   1499
1956-01-01, 1,  2,  2,  -2
1956-01-02, 2,  3,  3,  -1
1956-01-03, 3,  4,  4,  0
1956-01-04, 4,  5,  5,  1
1956-01-05, 5,  6,  6,  2
```

I read it as

```
dfr      =  pd.read_csv(f_name,
                            skiprows     = 0,
                            header       = [0,1,2,3], 
                            index_col    = 0,
                            parse_dates  = True
                            )
```

I would like to get the value of the first level according to the level 0 value.
I try to make myself clear. I would like to select the column '01090BL' (header level 0) and then I would like to get the value corresponding to the level 1 (named 0).

I have try the following:

```
dfr[['00590BL']['lat']]
```

a sort of matrix between headers. I get an error. I thing that I need a glue on multiindex handling.

I expect a sort of this:

```
value = dfr[['00590BL']]['lat']
```

with value=613297

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`MultiIndex.get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html#pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values):

```
dfr['00590BL'].columns.get_level_values('lat')[0]
```

Output: `'613297'`.

*Make sure than you don't have spaces when reading the data, you might need to add the `sep=',\s*', engine='python'` parameters in `read_csv`.*